# Deploying pub/sub spring application with google cloud run

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I have a very simple pub/sub application written in Spring Boot that **pulls** messages from a subscription and logs them. I followed this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-gcp-pubsub/). I have created a docker image from this program and can successfully run it locally and it picks up pub/sub messages that I create. When I push this image to Google Cloud Run it runs the docker image successfully however it doesn't pick up any pub/sub messages.

The strange part is that if I create a docker image from the program that doesn't have a HTTP server for Cloud Run's [healthchecker](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting) the application actually **picks up** pub/sub messages in Cloud Run, however after 4 minutes without a health check Cloud Run shuts down the service. For a healthcheck service  I use [spring-boot-starter-web](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web) which runs an Apache Tomcat server on port 8080. I can run this program locally  with the healthcheck service and it picks up pub/sub messages.

It seems that the HTTP server is stopping the pub/sub messages from getting pulled in Cloud Run. I'm not sure why that occurs because a pull subscription in pub/sub simply sends HTTP requests and awaits a response.

Comment: What's the logic of your app? When the container is started it pull the PubSub messages? Do you make request to start this container? Why pulling message instead of pushing message to HTTP CLoud Run endpoint?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere the logic of the app is literally just to consume messages from pub/sub and log them. I chose to pull as it seems to be the default method for most use cases and it requires the least amount of setup.

Comment: Do you call your Cloud Run endpoint or not? If so, how and with which product?

Comment: You've probably figured this out by now but for others' reference, subscriptions to PubSub for Cloud Run need to be Push subscriptions -- PubSub invokes the service with a POST to an HTTP endpoint.